# Best way to recruit a virtual team to a "garage" software project?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, projects, collaboration

I have a working prototype for a killer app implemented in C# for Windows Mobile. It needs to be packaged into a commodity and efficiently sold. Possibly also converted to a web-centric platform.

Now I'd like to assemble a community of seasoned, possibly semi-retired IT professionals. They should be willing to work for fun and free, with an eye to future profits. I realize not many people have the option to risk their time on something like this, but - hey - on a global scale there should be more than one.

I've googled variants of the above, but no dice. And I don't really see SourceForge et al as venues for recruiting, but more as the place where you MIGHT put your code base when the project is under way. I'm not well versed in Open Source, and I'm not sure I want to "open the kimono" on the source until there's been some modicum of vetting process (goes both ways, of course).

So, rephrasing the question: what is the best site for recruiting people to a project like this?

Comment: "IT professionals" - can you be more specific?  I don't think anyone knows what "IT" really means.  I'm guessing you want "programmers".

Comment: If you believe in your idea so much, why won't you risk your own money?

Comment: 1) IT professionals = developers/coders/programmers... testers/technical writers/web marketing gurus. Probably semi-retired. 

2) Already have. AND time is money. I'm risking my time, I'm not betting the farm. Having a killer app does not mean you'll be first to market with success.

Comment: But when you don't believe enough to spend your money, why would other good people believe enough to spend their time (which, as you say, is fungible with money)? You will need some other incentive.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you may want to go with a social networking site like [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com).

Your best bet on a risky project like this is to work with people you already know, and who already know you. If there are some bonds of trust in place already, you'll have a vastly greater chance of success, and a lot fewer unexpected personnel problems. Extending this to a 2nd degree contact (someone who knows someone you know) is a good next step.

Only if you really have no other options should you start pulling in people you've got no prior connection with, unless a) you're famous, or b) you want to start paying them and go through a more intense vetting (hiring) process.

Comment: LinkedIn and Facebook might be common sense starting points, if there is no site that's more narrowly focused on getting collaboration projects off the ground.

Answer (score 2):

Posting here probably helps, too :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't work for free for anyone unless they were already a close friend. Too many ways to get screwed.

Comment: That's why I stressed the vetting process. There really ought to be a web-centric way to build trust to the point where one would consider contributing, even given the risk of getting screwed. The site I'm looking for would have functionality to support it. And your response is a piece of work :-).

Answer (score 2):

To write a commercial application asking others to contribute without getting paid - even if you would give them a profit later on - to me that looks difficult.

I think you'd be better off to release a first version, perhaps with some limits, of your software for instance on [XDA-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=260). If it gets popular, you will have many free beta-testers out there and probably a lot of "skinners" who would probably contribute free-of-charge for the grafical user-interface. At this stage, you will probably get to know other developers at XDA who could help out with some stuff. In the beginning you could ask for donations and if you get some, you know that you have a software that people would be prepared to pay for. Then later on you could release a "Professional version" with more features that you could charge for.

just my 2 cents

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I did have some idea about releasing the first version on Handango in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not well versed in Open Source, and I'm not sure I want to "open the kimono" on the source until there's been some modicum of vetting process (goes both ways, of course).

The best open source projects tend to be the ones that are developed with the mindset that nobody else will ever join your project.  Start out with something simple that you can code yourself and then start putting the word out once you have a decent prototype (and [treat every user as a potential volunteer](http://producingoss.com/en/managing-volunteers.html#users-to-volunteers)).  You may also consider recruiting anybody already in your network (friends, coworkers, etc) as they'd theoretically be more apt to join such a project.

It will be pretty difficult for you to get someone to commit to a project with a promising but early codebase.  It will be even more difficult for you to recruit people with no codebase and no money.

I'm speaking mostly about the open source world, but I'd imagine that this would apply to a small shareware app as well.  With that said, I'd recommend giving [producing open source software](http://producingoss.com/en/index.html) a read if you want to learn more about the open source process.

Comment: Good link to basic information I need. Will study that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on ceejayoz's answer:

Even if you're friends, it's a heckuva way to get screwed. Things get said, promised, and discussed over beer with friends. Later, when there's something to lose (codebase, cash, clients, options) suddenly people have different recollections about who was going to get what.

Even if it's your bestest buddy, write down the details of your agreement. The more complicated the agreement, the more necessary it is for each of you to have a lawyer look at it.

The potential problems multiply with strangers. One of my bosses was also general counsel and she once said "If you don't trust the person, it's impossible to write a contract that will ensure their compliance".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're a developer and that's what you want to continue doing.  If that's the case, I would recommend a joint venture.

That is, partner with someone who has the marketing skills that you need to get your product out to a wide range of people.

As far as places to look for those types of people, I would start at jvnotifypro.com and branch out from there looking for other sites similar to it.  I believe at that site they have a few posts that mention some of those other sites.

Depending on your marketing budget, you could also go the route of paying people to install your program, paying for leads, etc.  There's a lot of ways to market a program and to get the best coverage you really have to think outside the box.

Oh, you can also submit software to the sites that support PAD - I think there's an app called AutoSubmitPro that will do this for you.  That's a great way to get your software out there a bit so that people know about it.

Comment: Great! Jvnotifypro seems really close to my idea! And I'll be sure to check out AutoSubmitPro too.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jason.  The way I did it in the past was through my existing network augmenting my skill set.  Hopefully, it takes off from there!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best thing to do is come up with a sales pitch for the other people you want to join the project you will have to sell the idea to them the same way you would sell it to a customer, people have to believe in something if they are going to work for free.

Additionally if you expect a professional to work for free you are going to have to give them a stake in the company...how big a stake all depends on viability of the project and your negotiating skills.

Comment: Solid business-like advice. And I am working on a sales pitch. Or it's actually more of an "elevator pitch"....